# Memory & file loading c++?

Tags: c++, file, memory, loading

I have written a program that loads files and I wonder if someone could explain why loading a file a 2nd & subsequent times is quicker than the initial loading of the same file?

For example:

1. When loading a large file (500MB) for the first time, it takes longer than subsequent loading of the same file. It only takes a fraction of the time when loading the file the 2<sup>nd</sup> time.

This is case even though RAM usage drops in between (this behaviour also appears when restarting the program).


2. If I reboot my PC and/or don't run the program or reload the file after a while, situation #1 occurs again.

Environment:

- C++
- VS 2010 (MFC)
- Windows XP Home 32-bit
- File loading:
  I've tried fread() & others, but they all end up in similar results.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I'm not sure, though the cause of your issue is quite obvious to me.  It's also being closed as "off topic" _and_ "not a question".  Oh, I suppose the lack of a question mark might be related.

Comment: Yes & the earth rises & sets, but people still say sunset & sunrise. May be obvious but to others it may not. So much for no such thing as a stupid question haha. Anyways, am appreciative of those that have answered. Cheers :)

Comment: yeah, didn't mean to say the answer was obvious, but it's obvious _to me_.  I was thinking maybe it was considered "too obvious" by some people?  Maybe?  (Edit a questionmark into your question.)  (Also, the earth doesn't rise or set either.  It spins)

Comment: All good, good way to start Friday, with a laugh. Spin indeed ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your operating system will cache files in unused memory. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). This will disappear after reboots, or if you use a lot of memory, or if you open many more files. The details vary based on your operating system.

For a broader overview on modern computer architecture, [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7zSU9HI-6I) by Herb Sutter is good.

Comment: Thought something like this may of been the case but wasn't sure. Thanks for the links too. Is there any way to cache a file before loading it or something similar to speed up file loading?

Comment: You could trick it by seeking and reading through it at an interval ~= the page size, but your OS could decide not to cache it or to kick it out before you use it. On Linux, the best option would probably be to make a RAM disk and copy the file into it.

Comment: Obviously, I should add, the length it takes to load the file the first time is the cost of loading it into the cache - you can't make that disappear :) You can hide the latency by loading the file asynchronously while you do other stuff, though. (That's another question :))

Comment: @ReturnVoid: The file still has to go from disk to RAM in both cases, unless you start doing asynchronous execution, that won't actually make your code "faster".  However, one thing you _can_ do is look into memory/file mapping, which gives you direct read-only access to the OS' cached version, saving you a copy. This probably won't make much difference overall though.

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that your hard drive may have a cache.  The first time you read the file you're reading it straight from the platters.  The next time, the drive can serve it up from the cache.  After a delay (or a reboot), the file's contents are no longer in the cache and thus it gets served up from the platters again.

Comment: The cache on a typical hard disk is around 32MB (more for SSDs.) while this is definitely important, its probably not even hitting that on the second load. It's likely cached in RAM by the OS.

Comment: Good point.  +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a modern operating system, there is no such thing as "unused memory". That would be a total waste. What the OS does is that it keeps copies of files, directory structures, file metadata [such as where on the disk the data for a given file is] and other useful data in the "unused" memory.

So when you read a file, it gets loaded into memory. Assuming there is enough "unused" memory, that file will indeed sit there for a long time. Eventually it will probably get kicked out, because in your normal use of your computer, the email software, web browser, file-content indexer, anti-virus scanner, network time synchronizer, address book to mobile phone synchronizer and all the other background code that runs in your system, and all of these things will use up a little bit of "unused" memory.

So, yes, files are cached. A 500MB file in a system that has 4 or 8GB of RAM and isn't using all of that RAM will potentially sit there for minutes, hours or even days.

Answer (score 0):

Most hard drives have a cache these days, so once you've loaded once, it is in the cache. You probably don't want to load a file more than once though!

Comment: it's probably not the hard drive cache that's giving these savings.